# Apply plugin to multiple DIVs

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=A1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=A1"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=A2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=A2"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=B1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=B1"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=B2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=B2"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then using http://dbrekalo.github.io/simpleLightbox I have:

```
$('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
```

But this makes the gallery to "see" all images in page as the same gallery.

How should I call `simpleLightbox` so each Gallery Div is seen as a gallery?

Note that I have more than two galleries in page.

Comment: Grab all your <a> tag (link) elements, iterate over them, and call .simpleLightBox() on each one individually??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.each` on `.gallery` and initiate plugin to `a` of individual `.gallery`

```
$('.gallery').each(function(){
   $(this).find("a").simpleLightbox();
})
```